# Android remote service with same process name

Tags: android, service, multiple-processes

Right now, I am doing android software development with its remote service component.

Actually, I have two remote services ,let me call them service A and service B respectively (service A is declared before service B in the Manifest.xml file) , which do two different things.

The two service have the same attribute value of 'android:process' (both are :remote). The two services function well in most of the situations.

But I found that sometimes (this situation happens with high possibility, actually), service A cannot start successfully. To solve this problem, I tried to change service B's 'android:process' attribute value. And to my surprise, everything goes back to normal. Both services works fine.

I thought Android system should allow two processes with same name but different pids exist. And the 'android:process' attribute's value should not be the cause of the problem. Is there anybody can explain why what I did can solve this problem?

Comment: "service A cannot start successfully", what goes wrong?

Comment: it cannot be started. that's what i saw.